# Disable Share Extension options when use UIDocumentInteractionController and UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction, ios8-share-extension

I use to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` and `UIActivityViewController` to share data with a special `UTI`.

However, when other app use `Share Extension`, there will may options when share interface popup, such as `copy tp xxx` and `import to xxx`.

How can i disable those options or is there any other way can share data to Specified app which i can control.

//=======
my code is like this:

```
UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[itemUrl] applicationActivities:nil];
activity.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                   UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
[self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Array and add types which don't want to show to user, like this

```
NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                       UIActivityTypePrint,
                                       UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                       UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                       UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                       UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                       UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                       UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];

Create a instance of UIActivityViewController
And set following propery
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities
```

Comment: already do this，it can not prevent those app who has ``Share Extension``, it still show ``copy to xxx`` and ``import to xxx``

Answer (score 0):

I found out if you share as `NSURL`, you will get `copy to xxx` or `import to xxx`, but if you share as `UIImage`, you will not get that.

will show `import to xxx`

```
avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fileURL, nil] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

will not show

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL]];
avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:image, nil] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```